# Slow Tableview with custom cell with images, Swift 3 and core data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to solve this really slow, sluggish scrolling on my table.

I'm using core data wrapper AERecord to fetch the data, and it scrolls smooth without the `cell.toneImage.image = UIImage(named: tone.image)`

The images aren't big ( 350 X 170) but def freezes for a second as soon as I scroll enough to load a new image.

I checked for blended images in simulator, etc.. could it be the data being fetched + loading the image at the same time? Any ideas or suggestions?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! mwCellTableViewCell
    self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
}

func configureCell(_ cell: mwCellTableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let frc = fetchedResultsController {
        if let tone = frc.object(at: indexPath) as? Tone {
            // set data

            cell.toneTitle.text = tone.name.uppercased()

            let img:UIImage = tone.fav ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "likeBtnOn") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "likeBtnOff")
            cell.favButton.setImage(img, for: .normal)
            cell.favButton.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.favButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favme(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


            cell.toneImage.image = UIImage(named: tone.image)
            cell.toneImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
            cell.toneImage.clipsToBounds = true

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't fetch data from `CoreData` like this. If you fetch it in `cellForRowAt`, it will fetch data every time cell is reused. You better fetch the data outside of `UITableView` delegate chain. Such as `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is two way for solve this

1. fetch and set image in Background using async.
2. fetch image before reloading Tableview Data

Answer (score 0):

Is `tone.image` doing a lazy fetch? I haven't used `AERecord`, but that *could* be an expensive operation if it's lazy loading.

Have you tried doing that fetch on a background thread, so the main thread isn't blocked?

I'd be tempted to try this:

1. pass the `tone` object into your `mwCellTableViewCell`
2. `mwCellTableViewCell` tries to get `tone.image` in a background thread
3. when that call returns, jump back on to the main thread and set `self.image = toneImage`